# Перестает работать Hamburger Button

Tags: android, android-navigation-drawer

Добрый день. У меня снова вопрос по Drawer Layout, а именно по "Гамбургер кнопке".
На одном фрагменте у меня включены **Navigation Drawer** и "Гамбургер кнопка". При переходе на **2-ой** Фрагмент, я отключаю эту кнопку и включаю Home Button:

```
  toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
        toggle.syncState();
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
       drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

При возврате на **1-ый** Фрагмент, я отключаю **Home Button**, и возвращаю "Гамбургер кнопку". Она появляется, но перестает отвечать на нажатия. В чём проблема? Вот код возврата на **1-ый** фрагмент:

```
 setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);

        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(toggle);

        toggle.syncState();
       drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
```

Если при возврате добавить "Гамбургер кнопке" полную инициализацию:

```
toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
```

то картина становится еще страннее и запутанней. При **ПЕРВОМ** переходе с 1-ого фрагмента на 2-ой, во 2-ой фрагменте **Home Button** показывается правильно, при возврате на 1-ый фрагмент **Navigation Drawer** тоже работает, но при попытке перейти СНОВА на 2-ой фрагмент, в ТулБаре появляется Гамбургер кнопка, вместо **HomeButton'a** (который при первом переходе показывался). Вообщем, надеюсь кто-то сможет разобраться в моём вопросе и подсказать, где ошибка!

Answer (score 1):

```
drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
```

Такие команды грубые...и лучше их не использовать)

Такое решение Вам не подходит?

```
 toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onBackPressed();
        }
    });
```

Comment: тут вопрос не как вернуться назад, а по изменению кнопок в тул баре, перечитайте еще раз мой вопрос, пожалуйста.

Comment: Я думаю проблема в использовании этой части кода "getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);" поэтому кнопка не работает т.к. значение false

Comment: Можно конечно сделать проще) устроить работу fragment'ов а Activity и в каждой активити делать onBackPressed(); тогда у Вас не будет путаницы в таких делах. Я просто сам хотел устроить такую работу с фрагментами, но понял что это еще те танцы с бубнами и перевел fragment'ы в acitivity  и бед не имею терь)

Comment: Насколько мне известно, getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false); не влияет на работу Hamurger Button. Хотя я перепроверил, ничего не изменилось. По поводу второго коммента, у меня активи, в нём есть фрагмент(1ый). С первого фрагмента есть переход на второй фрагмент(он не относится к активити). Переходы работают, но при возвращении на первый фрагмент - перестает работать Hamburger Button. Да, танцы еще те.

Answer (score 1):

Может кому поможет. Если вместо стандартной кнопки тулбара имеется гамбургер с анимацией (`ActionBarDrawerToggle`), то переключение стрелка-гамбургер средствами ActionBar адекватно работать не будет.

Вызов `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(xxx);` при этом работает ровно 1 раз. После возврата к гамбургеру с помощью `toggle.syncState();` следующий вызов `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(xxx)` иконку на стрелку не меняет.

Решил проблему следующим образом:

Сначала получаю анимированную стрелку из ActionBarDrawerToggle:

```
DrawerArrowDrawable drawerArrow = toggle.getDrawerArrowDrawable();
```

У анимированной стрелки есть setProgress(0-1.0f). Прогресс 0f это гамбургер, 1f это стрелка. Вот так переключаю на стрелку:

```
drawerView.removeDrawerListener(toggle);
drawerArrow.setProgress(1);
backAvailable = true;
```

Вот так обратно:

```
drawerView.removeDrawerListener(toggle);
drawerView.addDrawerListener(toggle);
toggle.syncState();
backAvailable = false;
```

Ну и соответственно навешиваю листенер для реакции на нажатие:

```
toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (backAvailable) {
            onBackPressed();
        } else {
            if (drawerView.isDrawerOpen(layout_drawer)) {
                drawerView.closeDrawer(layout_drawer);
            } else {
                drawerView.openDrawer(layout_drawer);
            }
        }
    }
});
```